# How to use pace with ember cli application

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to use pace to show animation while models are load asynchronously

I installed it using bower and imported the js and css files.

```
app.import('bower_components/pace/pace.js');
```

Then I created a loading route

```
//app/routes/loading.js
var LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.restart();
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    this._super();
    return Pace.stop();
  }
});
```

But on application loading it says Pace is not defined. Shoudn't ember-cli set Pace as a global variable. what am I missing. What is the right way to integrate pace in your ember cli project?

Comment: You need to import it, as in the route.

Comment: how do i import it whats the package name. I tried using pace didnt work

Comment: Wait a sec is it just giving you the warning (JSHint) or you can't use Pace at all?

Comment: @ptwo: Hii, is that pace addon worked for you??

Comment: @mohan.gade Yup It did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ember-cli doc](http://www.ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies):

> Note: Don’t forget to make JSHint happy by adding a /* global MY_GLOBAL */ to your module, or by defining it within the predefs section of your .jshintrc file

Once you include the file in the brocfile, restart your server and configure jshint to ignore the Pace global, to make sure that Pace is being loaded `console.log(Pace);` in your route, it should give you the Pace object.

Comment: It should be noted that you fist have to define document/window un predefs before defining other packages like Pace.